# Emails not going through properly to a single domain

Tags: email, office365, spf

I've searched all around, made several changes over the past two weeks, and still no luck so here I am.

We just put up a new site, and there are 3 different forms. Each form sends to a different email of theirs, a forwarder that sends to the same email of theirs (I had to make this after I figured out there was a problem with them not receiving emails from the website), and one of our emails.

Currently, they use office 365 for their email. A few days ago I figured out to change the SPF record, so I added the IP of their current website.

Here is the current SPF record:

`v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com ip4:23.229.157.193 a ~all`

I'm stumped. I've sent test submissions, and they receive the forward, and I receive it from my email, but the email that it's supposed to be sent to doesn't receive it.

I don't have access to their office 365 account. I tried a different option of sending the emails through swiftmailer, but GoDaddy doesn't allow me to connect to their smtp details, so that's a bust.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and know of a solution? All help is greatly appreciated.

**THE SOLUTION:**

After hours of calling, I was able to get the problem solved. I should have edited this earlier, but better late than never. In cPanel, there is an area for routing mail. It was set to local, rather than remote. Every email that came through went to the local emails, and since their were none, they were discarded. After changing the option to remote, the emails started flowing through. After the 3rd or 4th call, I reached someone who's actually dealt with this problem because he explained what was happening and the fix in under two minutes, unlike the others. I hope this helps anyone in the future with the same problems I encountered.

Answer (score 0):

If you've configured SPF on your sending smtp server, you can configure a       `_dmarc`
DNS record with an email address for the receiving server to send mail reports to...

Better yet, if this 'new' server is not required to be fully operational while you set up everything - you can set the _dmarc record to tell the receiving server to reject anything that doesn't pass the SPF test.

In any case, if you are setting up an email server that will send messages to any outside Internet address, and you have the ability to install software on the server - you should install and configure:

SPF, DKIM, and have a dmarc DNS record.

If you don't have these items, it's very likely much of your site's notification email will end up in the subscribers' spam box, or worse rejected by the receiving server.

Several good websites that have helped me:

- [unlocktheinbox.com](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com)
- [dmarcian.com](https://dmarcian.com/)
- [emailsecuritygrader](http://emailsecuritygrader.com/)
- [protodave.com dkim key checker](https://protodave.com/)
- [appmaildev.com domainkeys test](http://appmaildev.com/en/dkim)
- [gettingemaildelivered.com](http://www.gettingemaildelivered.com/)